# Unresolved reference: databinding in Android studio 4.1.3

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I face a wired behavior after following a lot of answers here in SO and other answers to solve but still stuck in it.

I added to app Gradle

```
  buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

and my activity_main.xml is wrapped by layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <data> </data>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.MainActivity" />
  </layout>
```

and I tried as well to add these to gradle.properties

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

and I already have

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image: Main Activity]
it shows no error when open the activity and as well when changing the name to another it also appears to be generated but whenever I run I got this error

```
Unresolved reference: databinding
```

[image]

How I can solve this?

**update 1
I already did clean and build multiple times, closed the android studio and opened it, as well did Invalidate Cache/Restart.

Comment: Did you manage by anyway fix this issue , I'm facing the same one now ?

Answer (score 4):

Please go to File->Invalidate Cache/Restart-> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 1):

After you add this to the gradle file:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

Make sure you click Sync Now. Otherwise you wont be able to do the next step.

[image]

Next step, in xml file, on

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.YourAppLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

right click, and you will get this menu:

[image]

Click on "convert to data binding layout". If you do not get this setting in your android setup, this should be a boilerplate layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using databinding the view-ids change names as described here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics#2

> Step 4: Use the binding object to replace all calls to findViewById()
> You can now replace all calls to findViewById() with references to the
> views that are in the binding object. When the binding object is
> created, the compiler generates the names of the views in the binding
> object from the IDs of the views in the layout, **converting them to**
> **camel case**. So, for example, **done_button is doneButton** in the binding
> object