# Android data binding not working (compileSdkVersion 31)

Tags: android, android-databinding, targetsdkversion

I'm trying to implement data binding in my app and failing miserably. I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem, so I'm hoping someone here has an idea as to why this is happening.

When I follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics?hl=tr#2) from Android Kotlin Fundamentals with the provided starter app, data binding works perfectly, no problems at all. But when I do the same thing in my own project, it won't compile. I think there is something wrong with generating the needed files.

From what I've gathered, it has something to do with the compile sdk version. If I make a new project with this build.gradle file, everything works, so I know it's not a spelling error or a missing  tag.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.databinding"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
   }

   dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

BUT! When I update things according to Android Studio's recommendations, everything stops working. These are the only things that change in the file:

```
    compileSdkVersion 31
    targetSdkVersion 31

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```

I can see data binding related folders/files appear in app > build > generated in file explorer, so there is something happening, but nothing shows up in Android Studio. I've tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated). How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335970/unresolved-reference-databinding-in-android-studio-4-1-3/70342315#70342315

Comment: You are right! Replicated easily by creating new project, added databinding and converted layout to using databinding. Could not fix besides using compileSdkVersion 30 and downgrading appcompat to 1.3.0. Seems like a bug but will check more next week. If you solved the issue, please post a solution.